# Proving that $k!$ is the largest integer that divides the product of any k consecutive integers (no binomial)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So far I have that $k$ consecutive integers $(d+k)(d+k-1)(d+k-2) \cdots (d+1) = \frac{(d+k)!}{d!}$. How can I prove that $k!$ is the largest integer that divides the product of any $k$ consecutive integers without using the binomial theorem?

Comment: I thought that the largest integer that divides $\frac{(d+k)!}{d!}$ is the number $\frac{(d + k)!}{d!}$.  Am I missing something here?  What is "the largest integer" supposed to mean here?

Comment: k! is the answer in the book, and the original question is correct. I'm as confused as you are.

Comment: I would assume that the book wants you to fix $k$ and compute the gcd of all the numbers $k!/0!$, $(k+1)!/1!$, $(k+2)!/2!$, and so on. In which case Omnomnom's answer shows that $k!$ is a common divisor, and the fact that $k!$ is one of these numbers shows that it's the greatest one...

Comment: That is, for "the largest integer that divides the product of $k$ consecutive integers" I would read "the largest integer that divides the product of *any* $k$ consecutive integers."

Comment: Edited the original question

Answer (score 1):

I assume you merely want to prove that $k!$ divides this product. Here's a combinatoric proof:

$(d+k) \cdots (d+1)$ is precisely the number of distinct arrangements of the numbers $1,2,\dots,(d+k-1),(d+k)$ that are $k$ digits long (and have no repetitions).  Consider the list of such arrangements.

Note that for any one subset of $\{1,2,\dots,(d+k)\}$ with size $k$, there are $k!$ arrangements consisting of these elements.  Thus, the number of elements is $k!$ multiplied by the number of subsets of size $k$.  The conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

$8\times7\times6$ is divisible by 42, not just $3!$