# How to prove that there are infinitely many integers n for which each of n, n+1, . . . ,n+ 1000 is composite.

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I need to prove this using the Chinese Residue Theroem. If i choose n even (n>2) then all even number are composite of course, but for the odd i don't know what to do. Plus, i don't see how the chinese residue theroem could be helpful. Thanks for your hints.

I know how to prove that there is infinitely prime (and infinitely composite) and i think i will have to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Take $n=k!+2$ Then all numbers $k!+2,k!+3,\ldots ,k!+m$ with $1\le m\le k$ are composite. From this statement your claim follows.

Reference: [Prove that $n! + k$ is a composite number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945871/prove-that-n-k-is-a-composite-number)

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but i need to use the Chinese Residue Theorem... Also this would be a good proof, but i also need n+1 and this one starts at n+2

Comment: @R-B No, it starts with $n,n+1,n+2,\ldots,$, right? We have $k!+3=(k!+2)+1=n+1$.

Comment: But yes, you are right. There is also a nice solution using CRT, see the duplicate Bill pointed out..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Try to prove that for all $k\geq 0$,
$$n=(1002+k)!+2$$

satisfy the property.

Comment: Where does that n comes from?

Comment: From my mind. The question is to find $n$ such that, so you can drop it and verify that it satisfies the given property.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, but from which portion of your mind, the left parietal lobe or the right?